# Sequelize, How to bulk increment/decrement multimple columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am building an ecommerce website,
When a client places an order, after some kind of verification, I want to decrement the stock 9in packageTypes table, availableQuantity column), but for multiple items, since a client might order multiple products.

order details array example :

[image]

Database Relation:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need to insert one row in orders and a row in orderDetails for each row in your order, and update the corresponding row in packageTypes with the reduced quantities. You need to think about what to do if the quantities available are insufficient so there's some program logic to do.

Comment: yes for this I handled everything, but It is the increment or decrement multiple packageTypes at once, depending on old values

Comment: I think you need to do an UPDATE for each one separately. You can use SET availableQuantity = availableQuantity - [qty]

Comment: You probably should use a transaction for this so you can rollback all changes you made processing the order if something goes wrong.

Comment: can you explain more about transactions? is it a sequelize thing?

Comment: You use them when you want all of a bunch of changes to happen, or none of them. You start a transaction, by issuing an SQL statement, do your changes, them commit those changes if everything was okay. If not okay you can issue a rollback command and it undoes all the changes you've made in the transaction.